# Open Internal Jframe after clicking button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have written this code 
EmployeeTable.java

```
package com.xyz.view.employeelist;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import com.xyz.view.iframe.employeedetail.EmployeeofficeDetail;

public class EmployeeTable extends JFrame
{
private JTextField Find;
private JLabel jFind,jDepartment,jDesignation,byName,bySalary;
private JButton SearchButton,add_Employee,getList,removeEmployee,save;
private JComboBox<String> Department, Designation;
private JTable EmpTable;
private JScrollPane  EmpTableScrollpane;
private JRadioButton sortByName,sortBySalary;
private ButtonGroup radioButton;
EmployeeofficeDetail e;

EmployeeTable()
{   

    setLayout(null);

    //------------ Text Feild ---------------------------
    jFind = new JLabel("Find :");
    jFind.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    jFind.setBounds(10, 20, 40, 20);

    Find = new JTextField(5);
    Find.setBounds(70, 20, 100, 20);

    //--------------------- Search Button -------------------------
    SearchButton = new JButton("Search");
    SearchButton.setBounds(190,20, 80, 20);

    //--------------------------- Get all list -------------------------

    getList = new JButton("Get All Employee List");
    getList.setBounds(160, 360, 200, 20);

    //---------------------- Add new Employee button -----------------

    add_Employee = new JButton("ADD Employee");
    add_Employee.setBounds(10, 400, 120, 20);

    //--------------------- Remove Employee Button --------------------

    removeEmployee = new JButton("Remove Employee");
    removeEmployee.setBounds(150, 400, 140, 20);

    //---------------------- Save Button -------------------------

    save = new JButton("Save");
    save.setBounds(310, 400, 100, 20);

    //------------------- Department Combobox ----------------------

    jDepartment = new JLabel("Department");
    jDepartment.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    jDepartment.setBounds(10, 50, 90, 30);
    String department[]={"Select Department","Software Development","Testing","Database","Financial","Planning","Human Resources"};
    Department = new JComboBox<String>(department);
    Department.setBounds(100, 50, 200, 30);

    //----------------- Designation Combobox -------------------------

    jDesignation = new JLabel("Designation");
    jDesignation.setBounds(10, 100,90, 20);
    jDesignation.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    String post[]={"Select Designation","Junior Developer","Senior Developer","Project Manager","Manager","Tester","Trainee"};
    Designation = new JComboBox<String>(post);
    Designation.setBounds(110, 100, 200, 30);

    //--------------------- Table -------------------------------

    Object[] column = {"ID","Name","salary","Designation","Department","Date of Joining"};
    Object[][] data = {{1,"amit"},{2,"raj"},{3,"ram"},{4,"rina"},{5,"sara"}};
    TableModel emp = new DefaultTableModel(data, column);
    EmpTable = new JTable(emp);
    EmpTableScrollpane = new JScrollPane(EmpTable);
    EmpTableScrollpane.setBounds(10, 140, 480, 200);

    //--------------------------- Radio Buttons -------------------------

    radioButton = new ButtonGroup();

    sortByName = new JRadioButton("Sort Table By Name");
    sortByName.setBounds(10, 430, 160, 20);

    sortBySalary = new JRadioButton("Sort Table By Salary");
    sortBySalary.setBounds(200, 430, 160, 20);


    add(jFind);
    add(Find);
    add(SearchButton);
    add(jDepartment);
    add(Department);
    add(jDesignation);
    add(Designation);
    add(EmpTableScrollpane);
    add(getList);
    add(add_Employee);
    add(removeEmployee);
    add(save);

    radioButton.add(sortByName);
    radioButton.add(sortBySalary);
    add(sortByName);
    add(sortBySalary);

    add_Employee.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            if(a.getSource()==add_Employee)
            {
            e = new EmployeeofficeDetail();
                e.setTitle("Registration Form");
                e.setVisible(true);
            }       
        }
    });
} 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    JFrame f=new EmployeeTable();
    f.setVisible(true);;
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

And EmployeeOfficedetail.java

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class EmployeeofficeDetail extends JInternalFrame
{
private JTextField name;
private JLabel jName;
private JButton jSave,jNext;
private JComboBox<String> jDepartment;

public EmployeeofficeDetail()
{
    jName = new JLabel("Employee Name");

    name = new JTextField();

    jSave = new JButton();

    jDepartment = new JComboBox<String>();

    add(jName);
    add(name);
    add(jSave);
    add(jDepartment);
}
}
```

I want to open EmployeeOfficedetail frame on clicking add employee button so that emploeetable frame should be disappear but my code is not working. and also how to write actionlistener for combobox and radiobutton in my code so table value can be sorted accordingly.for example if i select radio button sort by name it will sort table according to name.

Comment: Let me get this straight.. you want to close your main application JFrame and open a JInternalFrame? That's not going to work. JInternalFrame should be added to a JDesktopPane which is inside a JFrame. Maybe you want to look into using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to just switch between panels inside the frame

Comment: Or maybe you just want to use a modal JDialog. It seems appropriate for what you're trying to do. You can see more at [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Where did you set bounds for the EmployeeofficeDetail instance and where its added to the JFrame instance? Also its recommended to use JDesktopPane and add JInternalFrames to it.

Comment: as peeskillet has mentioned, you should want to use CardLayout and also check [The use of multiple JFrames, Good Bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice), also **don't** use `null layout`, Swing is designed to work with [`Layout Managers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) such as `CardLayout` or combination of them.